# Integrating google Speech Listener on Samsung Galaxy 4

Tags: speech-recognition, wear-os, recognizer-intent, samsung-galaxy-watch

[image]We developed an app that needs to work on all smartwatches with wearOS. The app is installed on Ticwatch and it works perfectly well.

In the same app, with the same wearOS version, we are facing an issue on Samsung smartwatch Galaxy 4 with a speech listener.
We get the following error:

```
E/SpeechRecognizer: no selected voice recognition service
```

(The smartwatch is properly installed with all the latest versions)

does anyone have an idea, of what can it be or what we need to do in order to make it work on Samsung Galaxy 4 and 5?

Comment: What's the result of a call to [SpeechRecognizer. isRecognitionAvailable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer#isRecognitionAvailable(android.content.Context))? Please share your [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi Gustavo, this is my first use of StackOverflow. I didn't know if I should use the Answer or comment. I apologies If I used a wrong tool.

Comment: No worries, welcome to SO! You should edit your original question, adding the information requested.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me that I need to edit my question.